# Access value in expand and use it in filter (Graph API)

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get generate a list of users that has the same manager in the Azure AD using the Graph API.

Using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$expand=manager($select=id)&$select=userPrincipalName,manager` will give be the necessary id for the managers set for the users.

I would now like to get all users with a certain manager id. I can't figure out how I use the id from manager field. This query doesn't work, it returns all users.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$expand=manager($select=id;$filter=manager/id eq '<manager id>')&$select=userPrincipalName
```

If I instead have the filter after the select I get the manager object itself since it seems to take `manager/id` as the `id` for the manager.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$expand=manager($select=id)&$select=userPrincipalName,manager&$filter=manager/id eq '<manager id>'
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the users with specific manager id use below api request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/XX/directReports
```

XX- It is Manager Id

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this would be the easiest solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you need to write your custom logic in your code to filter the users who have the same manager. According to [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http),

> $expand is not currently supported with advanced queries.

[image]

And per my test, when we used `expand` in graph SDK, it will [return null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72052863/14574199) property when a user doesn't have a manager, you may try to avoid null reference exception when writing your custom logic to do a filter.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right. For now it's not possible.